# How to use fetchNewObject with update.one ReactiveMongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Previously I used findAndUpdate and could add `fetchNewObject = true` so I was able to do something like this after the query:

```
.map(_.result[WhicherReport].getOrElse {
  throw new NoSuchElementException
})
```

but I'm using transaction now and could only perform `update.one(...)` and there is no option to pass it `fetchNewObject`, what can I do?

This is my func:

```
  def someUpdateFunc(collection: BSONCollection, metadata: Metadata, ids: List[String]): Future[UpdateWriteResult] = {
    collection.update.one(
      q = Json.obj("metadata" -> metadata,
        notLocked(now)),
      u =  Json.obj("$set" -> Json.obj("expenses.$[elem].paired" -> true)),
      upsert = false,
      multi = false,
      arrayFilters = Seq(BSONDocument("elem.id" -> BSONDocument( "$in" -> ids))),
      collation = None)
  }
```

and I want to return the new updated case class using ReactiveMongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use `fetchNewObject` with an [`update` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/), as it's not an option supported by this command.

You seems to think that `findAndModify` cannot be used with transaction, which not the case: [it can be used with transaction](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/test/scala/FindAndModifySpec.scala#L156).

```
for {
  ds <- db.startSession()
  dt <- ds.startTransaction(None)

  coll = dt.collection(colName)
  _ <- coll.findAndUpdate(selector, james, upsert = true)
} yield ...
```

If you still want to use `update` for unmentioned reason, then you will need to execute a `find` after, in the same transaction.

> P.S. `.getOrElse { throw new NoSuchElementException }` is quite a code smell, which should be discouraged (and rather compose).

Comment: can I use JSONCollection in the transaction instead of BSONCollection like this? ```reportCollection = dbWithTx.collection[JSONCollection](collection.name)```

Comment: cause I moved to findAndUpdate but now I get different errors since I need to use JSONCollection to be able to parse my returned object

Comment: but getting this error: ```errmsg=BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.txnNumber' is the wrong type 'int', expected type 'long'```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `findAndModify` or `update`, check the version (latest being 0.20.12-fix1). I would also add that mixing JSON & BSON there doesn't seem useful.

Comment: the connection is, if I use BSONCollection I CANT do findAndUpdate, only if I use JSONCollection I can, but then reactive throws this error above...

Comment: also, in reactiveMongo documentation they show that they use BSONCollection. so only then I can use findAndUpdate

Comment: so if I need to use BSONCollection it means I cannot use findAndUpdate and this means I have to add another find to fetch the newly updated object @cchantep

Comment: There is a deep misunderstanding. Please read the documentation. BTW JSONCollection will be removed.