# Fail to run 2 findAndUpdate queries inside a MongoDB 4.0 transaction

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have two queries I want to inside the transaction, each separately works, but when trying them both together I get this weird error:

```
  "errmsg": "Only servers in a sharded cluster can start a new transaction at the active transaction number"
```

The behaviour I understood is that you can't begin with `findAndUpdate` if you have more than 1 query in a transaction...

This is what I'm trying to run:

```
  def testFunc(metadata: Metadata)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = for {
    dbWithSession <- collection.db.startSession()
    dbWithTx <- dbWithSession.startTransaction(None)
    coll = dbWithTx.collection[BSONCollection](collection.name)

    _ <- queryOne(coll, metadata)
    _ <- queryTwo(coll, metadata)

    _ <- dbWithTx.commitTransaction()

    _ <- dbWithSession.endSession()
  } yield Unit
```

Both of them are find and update's queries, first one looks like this:

```
  def queryOne(collection: BSONCollection, metadata: Metadata) = {
    collection.findAndUpdate(
      selector = BSONDocument(s"metadata" -> metadata),
      update = BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("expenses.$[elem].paired" -> true)),
      fetchNewObject = true, upsert = false, sort = None, fields = None, bypassDocumentValidation = false, writeConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged, maxTime = None, collation = None,
      arrayFilters = Seq(BSONDocument("elem.id" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> List("1","2"))))
    )
  }
```

Does anyone see why I might get this error...?

The weirdest part is that they work separately, if I comment out one of them no issue.

using:

- Scala 2.12
- MongoDB 4.0
- [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) 0.18.8-play27
- Playframework 2.7

Comment: The message is quite clear, transaction is only available on valid replicaset or shardset

Comment: @cchantep but if both of them ```update.one``` no issue. would appreciate if you could help for me as its not as clear to me

Comment: There is nothing specific to any command about transaction + the error clearly comes from the server, not the driver

Comment: im not blaming it on the driver, just trying to figure out why only 1 findAndModify is possible in a mongo transaction. you said "transaction is only available on valid replicaset or shardset", but im able to perform a transaction, i get this error on a certain scenario and im trying to figure out what is happening

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: Add to question: server version, driver version, link to documentation for transaction use you are following.

Comment: @D.SM added to the question

Comment: I suggest enabling command monitoring if provided by  the driver and verifying the f-a-u commands use different tx numbers, which I believe would be required by driver specifications.

Comment: As [previously said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62812419/how-to-use-fetchnewobject-with-update-one-reactivemongo#comment111079855_62813433), first upgrade: there are ~10 months between 0.18.7 and latest 0.20.12-fix1.

Comment: Multiple `findAndUpdate` are working fine in a transaction in [integration tests](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/pull/951/files#diff-4f84773cfb31ae61b5112c9ce4d33a19R179)

Comment: @cchantep I can't really perform this update currently since I just need to add something small in a certain class which is big and its a part of the work project. so unfortunately I can only move forward to 0.19 since higher versions required additional code change which I can touch right now.

Comment: @cchantep now I tried to move to work with JSONCollection instead of BSONCollection and I get the  error ```errmsg=BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.txnNumber' is the wrong type 'int', expected type 'long'```. if you could open a chat with me that would really help me.

Comment: @cchantep above 0.19 also indexes is changed and there s no examples for the new way to use indexes in the documentation. I guess I would move back to 0.18 and use only 1 findAndUpdate which worked for me. you keep on sending me to the documentation and its really unclear, at least to me. thanks